# Need assistance using a JOIN to retrieve sums, or 0 from the RIGHT table if there is no entry present

Tags: mysql, left-join

I need a bit of assistance with the following query.  I'm sure I'm overthinking this, but here goes:

```
    SELECT 
        bc.name, 
        bc.category_id,
        bc.ref_id,
        COALESCE(bc.parent_id,bc.category_id) as parent_category_id,
        (select name FROM budget_categories bc2 WHERE bc2.category_id = bc.parent_id) as parent_name,
        (select ref_id FROM budget_categories bc2 WHERE bc2.category_id = bc.parent_id) as parent_ref_id, 
        COALESCE(sum(bee.amount),0) as amount
    FROM 
        budget_expected_expenses bee, budget_categories bc 
    WHERE 
        bc.group_id IN (1,139) AND
        bee.group_id = 1 AND
        bee.date BETWEEN '2012-01-01' AND '2012-01-31' AND 
        bee.cat_id = bc.category_id 
    GROUP BY bee.cat_id ORDER BY bc.ref_id ASC
```

Basically the goal is to return the sum of each category in the 'bc' table (whether created by the group or the headquarters -- in this case 1 and 139 respectively) from the 'bee' table.  If there is no entry in 'bee' for the specific group, I need it to return 0.  However, this query only returns sums for values that actually have entries in the 'bee' table.  I'm sure there's something I'm missing but, well, I'm missing it.  Thanks in advance.

NOTE:  I've tried various JOINS and nothing seems to work.  Obviously it's possible, I'm just blanking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'v rewritten using newer ANSI style than older format of listing tables and explicitly adding the joining criteria in the WHERE clause.  This way you should better see the relationship of how each table is related to the others and the explicit limits (such as date criteria) you want applied to those JOINED elements.  The where clause is left with just the criteria against the first table of the select.

I've applied TWO joins to the category table, once based on your intent to find the PARENT category and name and reference ID (provided a parent ID exists).  If not, it will look at the Default category ID found.

The only hiccup I THINK I see is the join to the expected expenses where your criteria is only that of group_ID = 1, yet your criteria for the budget categories is either 1 OR 139 (via in clause).  If they are in-fact SUPPOSED to be the same, then adjust the join to be

" AND bc.group_ID = bee.group_ID"

Finally, confirm what you want grouped by... the original category, or the parent its associated with, but that too is your call.

```
SELECT 
      bc.name, 
      bc.category_id,
      bc.ref_id,
      COALESCE( bc.parent_id,bc.category_id) as Which_Category_id,
      COALESCE( bcParent.Name, bcDefCat.Name ) as Category_Name,
      COALESCE( bcParent.Ref_ID, bcDefCat.Ref_ID ) as Category_Ref_ID,
      COALESCE(sum(bee.amount),0) as amount
    FROM 
        budget_categories bc 

           LEFT JOIN budget_expected_expenses bee
              ON bc.category_id = bee.cat_id
              AND bee.group_ID = 1
              AND bee.date BETWEEN '2012-01-01' AND '2012-01-31' 

           LEFT JOIN budget_categories bcParent
              on bc.parent_ID = bcParent.category_ID

           JOIN budget_categories bcDefCat
              on bc.Category_ID = bcDefCat.category_ID
   WHERE 
      bc.group_id IN (1,139) 
   GROUP BY 
      bc.category_id 
   ORDER BY 
      bc.ref_id ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

```
FROM budget_expected_expenses bee, budget_categories bc
```

If you want entries that appear in `bc` but not necessarily `bee`, then do a LEFT JOIN:

```
FROM budget_categories bc LEFT JOIN budget_expected_expenses bee ON bc.category_id = bee.cat_id
```

You'll also need to group by the column that's guaranteed to not be null:

```
GROUP BY bc.category_id
```

Also, your query is way more complicated than it needs to be, with the cross join and complicated subqueries. You could simplify it to something like this:

```
SELECT 
    bc.name, 
    bc.category_id,
    bc.ref_id,
    COALESCE(bc.parent_id,bc.category_id) as parent_category_id,
    parent.name as parent_name,
    parent.ref_id as parent_ref_id, 
    COALESCE(sum(bee.amount),0) as amount
FROM 
    budget_categories bc
LEFT JOIN
    budget_expected_expenses bee ON bc.category_id = bee.cat_id
LEFT JOIN
    budget_categories parent ON bc.parent_id = parent.category_id
WHERE 
    bc.group_id IN (1,139) AND
    bee.group_id = 1 AND
    bee.date BETWEEN '2012-01-01' AND '2012-01-31'
GROUP BY bc.category_id ORDER BY bc.ref_id ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

Suggest you rewrite the query to have a LEFT join:

```
SELECT 
    ....
    COALESECE(SUM(bee.amount,0.00))
FROM
    budget_categories bc 
    LEFT JOIN
    budget_expected_expenses bee ON bee.cat_id = bc.category_id
WHERE 
    ...
```

LEFT JOIN will always end up with *at least* one result record for every record in the left hand side of the join.  In the event there were no matching right-hand records, NULL will be used, which is why you need COALESCE() to turn that to a 0.00.